# AADB2C: Encryption key must be a 256-bit key

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I've copied a custom user flow for `PasswordReset`. After successful reset of password I'm getting error
`AADB2C: Encryption key must be a 256-bit key`
The original policy works fine.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Show what you actually did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of research and trail&error I finally found a solution for this.
When using the [Microsoft Identity Web](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web) package it works fine. Perhaps some setting in this library does some background magic and sets necessary client keys or tokens so that after successful password change now the user is redirected to the start page of my application.